# Looping through images in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a small tkinter GUI, which just contains an image of a thermostat. I have an image for each temperature to make a little animation of the temperature increasing. I have got this working to the point where it loops through all the images succesfully, however after the last image is displayed it just disappears. Here is my code so far

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1280x720")
root.configure(background='white')

def loopTemp(maxTemp):
    for x in range(0, maxTemp + 1):
        if x < 22:
            thermostat = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("thermo_"+str(x)+".png"))
            panel.configure(image = thermostat)

        panel.configure(text = str(x))      

        root.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(0.07)

light = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("light-on.png"))
thermostat = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("thermo_0.png"))


B = tk.Button(root, text ="Start", command= lambda: loopTemp(21))

panel = tk.Label(root, image = thermostat, text="0", compound=tk.CENTER, font=("Helvetica", 60), fg="white")

panel.configure(background='white')

B.pack()
panel.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill = "both", expand = "yes")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have to keep a reference to the image somewhere for as long as the widget displaying it exists, perhaps as an attribute of that widget - `panel.photo = thermostat` for example.  With only a local variable referencing the image, it will be garbage-collected as soon as that variable goes out of scope (Python cannot tell that Tk is still using the image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
...
thermostat = ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)
panel.configure(image = thermostat)
...
```

with:

```
...
panel.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)
panel.configure(image = panel.img)
...
```

In order to keep the reference of the image object wherever `panel` exists, thus have a consistent image display like suggested in the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916759/looping-through-images-in-tkinter#comment84840271_48916759).